# Ubuntu 20.10 installer thinks legacy system uses EFI booting

Tags: boot, uefi, 20.10

I have a Lenovo laptop with BIOS configured for legacy (non-efi) boot only.  I also have Windows and Suse  OS's installed.  When I install Ubuntu 20.10 by DVD, it warns me that I don't have an EFI partition and that bad things will happen if I don't create one.  This obviously wrong.  How can I make the installer realize this a non-EFI system?

Comment: Add the output of this command to your question (execute it in the live DVD): `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`

Comment: @adazem009 I have the same issue he has, only difference is that I am booting from a usb instead. The output I received from your command is "bios"

Comment: @Argaman Thank you. That command will check if the live USB/DVD is booted in EFI or legacy mode. The "bios" output means you're in legacy mode.

Comment: @adazem009 If so, why does it still gives the warning? And what can I do to fix it? Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: @Argaman I'm not sure... this is the first time I see something like that.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and found this is a Bug in Ubuntu 20.10 where the installer want an EFI partition even if the system is in Bios only.
Bug is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1893964
and according to it the fix will be probably on Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Still happening in 21.04 :-/

Comment: still happening with ubuntu 22.04 as well as kubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a partitioning tool like ' Minitool partitions' and then make a new partition with enough space on your hard drive. Make sure to turn it from NTFS /FAT32 to EX4 and make it / root type it worked for me. Hope this works