# What does /boot/efi do in my Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, disk-usage, grub-efi, boot-partition

When I `$cd /boot` to enter /boot directory and then `$ls -l`, it shows:

```
.........
drwx------ 2 root root      4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
.........
```

Here I just hide all other files shown in the directory.

But when I `$ls -l efi` as a root user, it shows:

> total 0

When I run `$df -h /boot/efi` , its shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       511M  4.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
```

When I run `$df -h | grep sda1`, it shows:

```
/dev/sda1       511M  4.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
```

When I run `$fdisk -l /dev/sda`, it shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119.25 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk model: GIM128
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x122b13d1

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 250068991 249016322 118.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 250068991 249016320 118.8G 83 Linux
```

I wonder why sda1 uses type of 'W95 FAT32' and what the efi is used for. I bought the Linux machine (industrial computer) from a vendor who told me they just installed the system by default settings. The OS is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` will show if your installation is in uefi mode or bios mode.

Comment: It shows BIOS.  So it means the installation is in BIOS mode? But how to explain /boot/efi?

Comment: yes bios mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286977/ubuntu-20-10-installer-thinks-legacy-system-uses-efi-booting

Answer (score 3):

Any UEFI based system - UEFI is the new firmware that replaced the 1980's BIOS - requires, for any UEFI mode installation, a small FAT32 formatted partition where the bootloader is installed or more than one if dual- or multi-booting. Additional explanation at the end.

**So, what you see is normal and expected in any computer from the last decade regardless of the preinstalled OS.**

BIOS and UEFI are firmwares.

The former was used for PCs and compatibles/clones since the first PC in 1981 until around 2008/9. Then the BIOS was replaced by a newer and a lot more feature rich firmware called UEFI. Then since 2012 and Windows 8 Microsoft pretty much "forced" all manufacturers to preinstall Windows in UEFI mode and GPT.

ou don't need and shouldn't "browse" /boot/efi (which BTW is just a mount point for the EFI System Partition) unless you know what you're doing. Instead, what you actually need to do is understand what UEFI is, how it boots and its requirements, particularly when dual-booting.

Comment: Replace BIOS? You mean there is no need of a separate BIOS in a ROM? The first step goes directly to /boot/efi? Not in line with Linux booting process described in https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-linux-booting-process-6-steps-described-in-detail/. I think /boot/efi is where the first part of bootloader resides, the rest is in /boot/grub. By the way, how can I browse the content of /boot/efi?

Comment: BIOS and UEFI are firmware. The former was used for PCs and compatibles/clones since the first PC in 1981 until around 2008/9. Then the BIOS was replaced by a newer and a lot more feature rich firmware called UEFI. Then since 2012 and Windows 8 Microsoft pretty much "forced" all manufacturers to preinstall Windows in UEFI mode and GPT. Your link is soooo outdated it stinks. That said, of course it's still valid for old computers with BIOS but obviously NOT for yours that has UEFI, not BIOS.

Comment: You don't need and shouldn't "browse" `/boot/efi` (which BTW is just a mount point for the EFI System Partition) unless you know what you're doing. Instead, what you actually need to do is understand *what* UEFI is, how it boots and its requirements, particularly when dual-booting.

Comment: Side note: If an answer is useful you should accept it. I'm not talking about this one specifically but  your other one. Please take the https://askubuntu.com/tour to understand how the site works.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Comments may be removed in the future. So, I suggest you [edit] your answer and consolidate all the extra information you provided in your comments and put them into your answer.

Comment: @FedKad Done! You're correct indeed but after more than 10 years explaining the same thing over and over I find myself being a lot more terse nowadays because this kind of questions are tiresome. It seems some people were living under a rock for this whole time.

Comment: That means you made the dumb move of installing in Legacy mode when you shouldn't. Indeed, even in that case the installer creates an EFI partition. And no, I'm not wrong.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I wonder why you like depreciating others while insisting on your own opinons, even it's apprently incorrect.

Comment: Based on what you have given us in the way of info, ChanganAuto is correct. Its just you also have MBR(msdos) partitioning, so could also have BIOS boot. It will depend on which version of grub you have installed. If you have the ESP - efi system partition mounted in /boot and has an entry in fstab, then it is UEFI. to confirm: `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`  More info & see all the links it has: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition

Answer (score 0):

Let me to have a summary and conclude the question.
After reading the answers and comments, I google relevant terminologies and believe that the question can be concluded as the following.
In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition, it says:

> UEFI provides backward compatibility with legacy systems by reserving
> the first block (sector) of the partition for compatibility code,
> effectively creating a legacy boot sector. On legacy BIOS-based
> systems, the first sector of a partition is loaded into memory and
> execution is transferred to this code. UEFI firmware does not execute
> the code in the MBR, except when booting in legacy BIOS mode through
> the Compatibility Support Module (CSM).

> The UEFI specification requires MBR partition tables to be fully
> supported.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) However, some UEFI implementations immediately switch to
> the BIOS-based CSM booting upon detecting certain types of partition
> table on the boot disk, effectively preventing UEFI booting to be
> performed from EFI system partitions contained on MBR-partitioned
> disks.[5]

Then to check whether my Linux machine uses GPT or MPR, I run `$ sudo parted -l`, it shows:

```
Model: ATA GIM128 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  primary   fat32        boot
 2      539MB   128GB  127GB  extended
 5      539MB   128GB  127GB  logical   ext4
```

The Partition Table field shows that I am using a msdos MBR partition table (the one still commonly used for Linux and Windows).

So, in conclusion, in my case although the boot partition(primary partition) is mounted on /boot/efi, it effectively uses a BIOS-based boot loader.